# error at line 148 on begin{center}--why is it happening?

Tags: errors

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{letter}  %inter office note /cover page vertical line template
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}                      %for color of table
\usepackage{booktabs}                        %for toprule midrule bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{multirow}           % Required for multirows
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}             %no hyphenation
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lastpage}                                     %toget last page number
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[en-US]{datetime2}
\usepackage[%
            height=8in,                 % height of the text block
            width=5.1in,                  % width of the text block
            top=78pt,                 % distance of the text block from the top of the page
            headheight=60pt,            % height for the header block
            headsep=12pt,                % distance from the header block to the text block
            heightrounded,               % ensure an integer number of lines
            %  showframe,              % show the main blocks
            verbose,                    % show the values of the parameters in the log file
            ]{geometry}
%header and footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\newcommand*{\plogo}{\fbox{$\mathcal{PL}$}}                 % Generic dummy publisher logo 
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}                        %best
%\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}            %footnotes will have symbols instead of    numbers
%\newcommand{\footer}{                                           %change the header or footer on a particular page
%   \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}%
%   \fancyhead{}
%   \fancyhead[c]{CONTENT}
%   \fancyfoot[L]{%
%       \footnotesize 
%       Typeset in \LaTeX}}
\fancyhead[R]{%
            \footnotesize 
                Special Assignment Wing\\
                Controllerate of Quality Assurance \\
                Armoured Vehicle Electronics\\
                Avadi, Chennai – 600 054}
\fancyhead[C]{%
            \includegraphics
            [scale=0.05]
                {../../‎⁨⁨LATEX⁩/⁨images/ashoka.png⁩} }  
\fancyhead[L]{%
            \footnotesize 
                File No: 48332/2019/ISO/1 \\dt 28 Jun 2019}
\fancyfoot[L]{%
            \footnotesize 
                 Typeset in \LaTeX} 
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newlength{\restofline}           
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \underline{\textbf{INTER OFFICE NOTE}}

    \underline{BOO: ISO 9001:2015}

\end{center}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Ref 
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item   CQA(AVL) ISM No AVL/20203/Est dt 19 Jun 2019.
        \item CQA(AVL) DO Part I Serial No 5 dt 29 Jan 2019.
    \end{enumerate}
    \item   Progress on the Board Proceedings was intimated to the Controller as under 
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Date :27 Mar 2019 
        \item Noting Sheet No :20908/ISO 2015/PC dt 27 Mar 2019. 
        \item   Dak Diary entry at Controller Sectt has been endorsed on the movement of the ibid noting sheet as 2184/C Sectt/27/3/19
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Second progress report 
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Date :27 Mar 2019 
        \item   Noting Sheet No :48332/2019/ISO/1 dt 27 Mar 2019. 
        \item   Dak Diary entry at Controller Sectt has been endorsed on the movement of the ibid noting sheet as 2188/C Sectt/27/3/19
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Third progress report
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Date :13 May 2019 
        \item   Noting Sheet No :20908/ISO 2015/PC dt 13 May 2019. 
        \item Dak Diary entry at Controller Sectt has been endorsed on the movement of the ibid noting sheet as 2408/C Sectt/13/05/19
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Leave period of Jt Controller(SA): 14 May 2019 to 23 Jun 2019

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item During the leave period above mentioned, Member No 1 is the Presiding offr of the BOO as per Rule, hence the query for the intervening period may be addressed to the offr concerned
    \end{enumerate}
    \item It is also intimated that as per the DO Part I published the mandate of the BOO expired on 30th Apr 2019. Additionally, the sanction for obtaining the ISO certificate from BIS has not yet been received from HQ DQAL till date, though forwarded on 21 Nov 2017.
    \item   Forwarded for info please
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{1cm}
\raggedleft{(JS Bibra)\\
    Colonel\\Jt Controller(SA)}

\raggedright \underline{Admin Officer/"O" Wing}\\ \vspace{1pt}
CQA(AVL)

\vspace{1cm}

\savebox\mybox{\hbox{\underline {Shri Peter J, PScO/ SA Wing } --\hskip 1pt}}
\noindent\usebox{\mybox}
\setlength{\restofline}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\wd\mybox-10pt\relax}
\begin{minipage} [t]{\restofline}
    Please intimate the progress of the Board wef 13 May 2019 onwards for the info of Controller. On file.
\end{minipage}  
\pagebreak
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fancyhead[L]{%cover page for key result areas
            \footnotesize 
                 File No: 20211/JC/SA \\dt 06 Sep 2019}
\raggedleft % Right align the title page    
    \rule{1pt}{\textheight} % Vertical line
    \hspace{0.05\textwidth} % Whitespace between the vertical line and title page text
    \parbox[b]{0.6\textwidth}{ % Paragraph box for holding the title page text, adjust the width to move the title page left or right on the page

        {\Huge\bfseries Key Result Areas \\[0.5\baselineskip] August 2019}\\[2\baselineskip] % Title
        \begin{itemize}
        \item {\large\textit{DGQA Unit Run Canteen\\ 
        \item ISO Certification 9001:2015\\
        \item CQA(AVL) Standing Orders}}\\[4\baselineskip] % Subtitle or further description
        \end{itemize}

        {\Large\textsc{colonel js bibra\\joint controller}} % Author name, lower case for consistent small caps

        \vspace{0.5\textheight} % Whitespace between the title block and the publisher

        {\noindent The Publisher~~\plogo}\\
        [\baselineskip] % Publisher and logo
    }
\pagebreak
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fancyhead[L]{%
    \footnotesize 
    File No: 48332/2019/ISO/2 \\
    dt 04 Jul 2019} 
\begin{center}
\underline{\textbf{INTER OFFICE NOTE}}\\
    \underline{BOO: ISO 9001:2015}
\end{center}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Ref
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item   CQA(AVL) ISM No AVL/20203/Est dt 19 Jun 2019.
            \item   CQA(AVL) DO Part I Serial No 5 dt 29 Jan 2019.
            \item   SA Wing L/No 48332/2019/ISO/1 dt 28 Jun 2109.
        \end{enumerate}
        \item   Progress on the Board Proceedings wef 13 May 2019 onwards is still awaited please.
    \end{enumerate} 
\vspace{1cm}
\raggedleft{(JS Bibra)\\
    Colonel\\Jt Controller(SA)}
\vspace{1cm}

\savebox\mybox{\hbox{\underline {Shri Peter J, PScO/ SA Wing } --\hskip 1pt}}
\noindent\usebox{\mybox}
\setlength{\restofline}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\wd\mybox-10pt\relax}
\begin{minipage} [t]{\restofline}
    Please intimate the progress of the Board.
\end{minipage}
\pagebreak
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fancyhead[L]{%
    \footnotesize 
    File No: 48332/2019/ISO/2 \\dt 07 Sep 2019} 
\begin{center}
    \underline{\textbf{INTER OFFICE NOTE}}\\
    \underline{DGQA URC}
\end{center}


\begin{enumerate}
    \item   Ref remarks of Controller on Noting Sheet dt 06 Sep 2019 enclosed.
    \item   Please progress the action on the remarks and put up completion report. 
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{1cm}
\raggedleft{(JS Bibra)\\
    Colonel\\Jt Controller(SA)}

\vspace{1cm}

\savebox\mybox{\hbox{\underline {Shri Peter J, PScO/ SA Wing } --\hskip 1pt}}
\noindent\usebox{\mybox}
\setlength{\restofline}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\wd\mybox-10pt\relax}
\begin{minipage} [t]{\restofline}
    Please intimate the progress.
\end{minipage}
\pagebreak
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your example code more minimal. There is a lot of code that is most likely not related to the issue.

Comment: It would appear that LaTeX cannot find the file `../../‎⁨⁨LATEX⁩/⁨images/ashoka.png`. For sure, if I add the option `demo` to the `\documentclass` directive, the code compiles without errors.

Comment: `{../../‎⁨⁨LATEX⁩/⁨images/ashoka.png⁩} }` seems to contain invisible caracters. You might want to correct that.